# I'm getting this error after 'upgrading' (happened as a result of trying to play music) within unity within chromebook

Tags: chromebook

This is what it gives me after both resaving a new crouton file over the old one and trying to update it with: `sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u`

It gives me this error:

```
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
Failed to complete chroot setup.
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

But, before this error occurred - it gave this one after solving it with the `sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n precise -u` :

```
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

I know the order is lacking but bear with it and if you need further explanation - well, I'm all ears.

Comment: I was having a fantastic day installing unity and then Minecraft when I noticed that in the menu bar there was an option to play an mp3 file so I did and then said I needed to upgrade and so I did - here is the result lol